# iOS Watch app fails to install - WatchKit 1.0 apps are no longer installable on this watchOS version

Tags: ios, watchkit, xcode11.4

I have added Watch App target for existing iOS app but I have problem to install it on watch simulator. It always fails with this message

```
This app could not be installed at this time.
Domain: IXUserPresentableErrorDomain
Code: 1
Failure Reason: Could not install at this time.
Recovery Suggestion: WatchKit 1.0 apps are no longer installable on this watchOS version.
--
WatchKit 1.0 apps are no longer installable on this watchOS version.
Domain: MIInstallerErrorDomain
Code: 133
User Info: {
    FunctionName = "-[MIInstallableBundle _isValidWatchKitApp:withVersion:installableSigningInfo:error:]";
    LegacyErrorString = UnsupportedWatchKitVersion;
    SourceFileLine = 683;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 10.15.4 (Build 19E287)
Xcode 11.4.1 (16137)
```

I have tried to create new sample app and it works fine. I compared both watch apps settings and they are same. Any idea what can be issue? Thanks

Comment: The watch SDK for your existing watch target is 1.0.  Change this.

Comment: @Paulw11 it is not. I checked it and there is even no option to use watch sdk 1.

Answer (score 1):

Found solution, which is totally unrelated to error message.

I changed **Valid architectures** in **Build settings** to **$(ARCHS_STANDARD)** for all targets.

Comment: I have this exact same problem, in the same Xcode version, but changing this setting did not help me.  I have multiple platform targets, iOS/tvOS/watchOS.  All the others install fine.  Watch app builds but then shows this error when installing on the sim.  Tried targeting watchOS 6.0 and 6.2

Comment: Update:  fixed!  For me I had to uncheck "Watch App Target -> Embed App Extensions -> Copy only when installing, then it worked

Answer (score 1):

Adding **WKApplication** key to watch app target plist and set it to true (Xcode 14.3 - No extension exists)

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the different deployment target for the "WatchKit App" & "WatchKit Extension".

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
I finally found a solution by creating the project from scratch. Moved all files into the new project from the old one.

---

I just realized the WatchOS deployment target is empty after creating the watch target. It is under the **project** settings, not the target settings.
Nevertheless, setting the target did not help me, maybe will help you.

[image: Build Settings]

Answer (score 0):

Updated fix -> Watch App Target
This solution worked for me try this out,
Refer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/74947725/9805273