# Can't install Watch app - WatchKit 1.0 apps are no longer installable on this watchOS version

Tags: xcode, swiftui, watchkit, apple-watch

I have Xcode 12, the newest version, from App Store. On my exising iOS project, I added a WatchKit app with deployment target of watchOS 7.0. However, when I try to run the watch app on simulator, it tries to install then gives me this error in an alert:

> **This app could not be installed at this time.**
> Could not install at
> this time.  WatchKit 1.0 apps are no longer installable on this
> watchOS version.

I don't know what's wrong with the target that causes it to give this error. Like said before, the deployment target for the app is watchOS 7 and the app uses SwiftUI. I also can't get a preview on SwiftUI because it gives me the same error saying cannot install. I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61635634/2631081), but it doesn't work at all.

Here are the error details:

```
This app could not be installed at this time.
Domain: IXUserPresentableErrorDomain
Code: 1
Failure Reason: Could not install at this time.
Recovery Suggestion: WatchKit 1.0 apps are no longer installable on this watchOS version.
--
WatchKit 1.0 apps are no longer installable on this watchOS version.
Domain: MIInstallerErrorDomain
Code: 133
User Info: {
    FunctionName = "-[MIInstallableBundle _isValidWatchKitApp:withVersion:installableSigningInfo:error:]";
    LegacyErrorString = UnsupportedWatchKitVersion;
    SourceFileLine = 698;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 11.0 (Build 20A5374g)
Xcode 12.0 (17219)
```

I have another iOS project with a WatchKit app that is running just fine.

Do you have this problem also or know how to resolve it? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This solution worked for me try this out,
Refer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/74947725/9805273